# Bootstrap column ordering with 3 column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3.2.1 ordering three column ordering issue.
Trying to order three columns like below img in  small screen.

[image]

---

In medium screen it should be like above image.
[image]

---

but ordering is not working if COL A height is greater than COL C
[image]

**code:**

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-7"> Col B </div>
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-pull-5"> Col A </div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-7"> Col C </div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avinvarghese/8aL3z36x/)

Comment: explain your problem using **words** instead of just sticking images on the question

Comment: It is not possible without some magical javascript :)

Comment: You could probably use Masonry layout style that can be done just using Css. Or you can wrap the Col b and Col  c into a div and position from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is float **B** and **C** to the right.

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c1s4evob/).

```
<style type="text/css">
    .A, .B, .C {
        background-color: DodgerBlue;
        color: white;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .A {
        height: 200px;
        line-height: 200px;
    }
    .B, .C {
        float: right;
        height: 75px;
        line-height: 75px;            
    }
</style>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 B">B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 A">A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 C">C</div>
```