# how to re-order elements in bootstrap in a specific way

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 5 I would like to achieve reordering columns between desktop and mobile like on this picture

[image: bootstrap 5 columns reordering]

I have tried the `order` classes and workaround with `position: absolute`, but that does not work as I would like to.

I also found there was somebody trying to achieve [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441773/re-order-bootstrap-columns), but probably with old bootstrap and without a satisfying solution (I would like to avoid `float`). Also, green plus red part can have higher height than blue one.

The simple code without reordering is here:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-xxl-6">
    <div style="height:20px; background-color:green;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-xxl-6">
    <div style="height:60px; background-color:blue;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-xxl-6">
    <div style="height:40px; background-color:red;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't be possible because in the second configuration you'll need to have the green and red columns nested inside a column which is a sibling to the blue one. You can't reorder across levels like that.

Comment: Although here's a similar question solved with floats (because that's what Bootstrap 3 used): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315211/bootstrap-column-ordering-with-3-column

Comment: More possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstrap+column+ordering

Comment: thanks. I have looked to some of those before without any luck. and thank you for the link with fiddle (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315211/bootstrap-column-ordering-with-3-column), but the solution will not work in bootstrap 5 unfortunately

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with bootstrap 5: http://jsfiddle.net/061kyL5e/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239816/discussion-between-koubin-and-isherwood).

Comment: I don't really have anything else to add. You may need to revise your overall strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display: flex` property, in bootstrap it would be the classes with`.flex- *`
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

and to better understand how the `display: flex` works
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You should copy the snippet demo down here and make changes to show your solution. I don't see how this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by duplicating the green section using different `.d-*` display utility classes. The first instance should be hidden above the breakpoint with `.d-xxl-none` and the second instance should be hidden below the breakpoint with `.d-none` and shown above with `.d-xxl-block`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-xxl-6 d-xxl-none">
    <div style="height:20px; background-color:green;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-xxl-6">
    <div style="height:60px; background-color:blue;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-xxl-6">
    <div class="d-none d-xxl-block" style="height:20px; background-color:green;"></div>
    <div style="height:40px; background-color:red; "></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I would like to avoid duplicate content. I made workaround with absolute positioning and padding